# Generating a grid-container style when mapping through an array

Tags: css, reactjs

**Summary**

I have the following chart image (react-vis):

[image: mychart]

My React code (below) is creating this with a `map` through an array.  How should I modify the code so the charts go across the page and are contained in some kind of fluid wrapper like this:

[image: desired output]

**What have I looked at/tried?**

I have basic understanding of HTML and CSS but would not know how to approach this kind of task and modify the code.

Would I need to use something like this and integrate with the code above?

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div className="grid-item">1</div>
  <div className="grid-item">2</div>
  <div className="grid-item">3</div>
  <div className="grid-item">4</div>
</div>
```

I would like to understand an effective way to do this please using CSS, bootstrap or whatever would be considered best practice.

**Code:**

MyComp.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import Example from "./plotBar.js"

function getJson() {
  return fetch("http://secstat.info/testthechartdata3.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
}

const MyComp = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getJson().then(list => setList(list))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((data, index) => (
        <Example
          key={index}
          data={data.map(({ id, count }) => ({
            x: id,
            y: count,
          }))}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComp
```

plotBar.js

```
import React from "react"

import {
  XYPlot,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  VerticalGridLines,
  HorizontalGridLines,
  VerticalBarSeries,
} from "react-vis"

export default function Example({ data }) {
  return (
    <XYPlot margin={{ bottom: 70 }} xType="ordinal" width={300} height={300}>
      <VerticalGridLines />
      <HorizontalGridLines />
      <XAxis tickLabelAngle={-45} />
      <YAxis />
      <VerticalBarSeries data={data} />
    </XYPlot>
  )
}
```

The data looks like this:

[image: data]

URL for JSON

http://secstat.info/testthechartdata3.json

Comment: Can you show how your data looks like? it seems like an array of arrays of objects

Comment: I added an image showing how the data looks. @DennisVash Thanks

Comment: Please add the actual code...

Comment: The URL was in the code but I have now pasted the JSON link at the bottom of the post for clarity @DennisVash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about `flex` and `flex-flow`, after that it just applying minor styling, this is CSS-in-JS example:

```
const Item = styled(Example)``;

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  ${Item} {
    margin: 0.5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: white;
  }
`;
```

[image: Edit suspicious-tdd-ror03]

---

```
const Item = styled(Example)``;

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  ${Item} {
    margin: 0.5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: white;
  }
`;

export default function Example({ data, className }) {
  return (
    <XYPlot className={className} xType="ordinal" width={200} height={200}>
      <VerticalGridLines />
      <HorizontalGridLines />
      <XAxis tickLabelAngle={-45} />
      <YAxis />
      <VerticalBarSeries data={data} />
    </XYPlot>
  );
}

const list = // fetch on mount

const MyComp = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      {list.map((data, index) => (
        <Item
          key={index}
          data={data.map(({ id, count }) => ({
            x: id,
            y: count,
          }))}
        />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that you wanted it in a grid, I will just leave the answer as another approach

Comment: Thanks for this.  So do I need to update my `plotBar.js` file with `Item`, `Container` and `Example` and then update `MyComp.js` with the updated `MyComp` function?  What is the `const list = // fetch on mount` for please?

Comment: You have sandbox attached